# iOS: Display a new scene after clicking an alertView button

Tags: ios, iphone

I am very new to iOS development so please forgive me if i ask something stupid.

So in one scene(let's say S1), after a button is clicked, an alertView will popup with two choices: YES and No. After you click YES and dismiss the alertView, i want to display a new scene(S2) rather than go back to the original S1.

What i tried was, i dragged a ViewController(S2) in the storyboard and add a new file(cocca touch class -> subclass of UIViewController) to the project(for example s2controller.h and s2controller.m). I then selected the new scene S2 in storyboard and in identity inspector i change its class to s2controller. Then i added some buttons in S2 so it's not an empty scene. And i went back to S1controller.m file and import s2controller.h and add the following code:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
// YES button is clicked
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        // Push the view controller.
        S2Controller *s2 = [[S2Controller alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:s2 animated:YES];

        NSLog(@"Push new scene successful.");
    }
    else{
        // do something
    }
}
```

There was no compile error. When i tested it with simulator, after i clicked YES from the alertView, the screen turned black but i can see the navigation bar was still up there. I can click the go back button in the navigation bar to go back to scene S1.
My question is: can i fix this by adding or editing some code, or is this 
whole idea is wrong from the beginning?

ps: i only use storyboard to create all the scenes, i don't have nib file in the project.

ps2: both scenes S1 and S2 have navigation controller embedded.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating new S2Controller without a view it is different from S2Controller Object in storyboard. What you should do is make a reference to storyboard controller and instantiate S2Controller with that reference (storyboard id).

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
S2ViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController@"S2ViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that definitely helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
    S2Controller *s2 = [[S2Controller alloc] init];
```

Good so far, *except* that that is not the same S2Controller whose interface you designed in the storyboard, so that's why it's black when you push it.

What you need to do is get a reference to the storyboard, and from there you instantiate the S2Controller that is *in the storyboard*, which you will do by having given it an identifier - i.e. you call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` to get the instance *from the storyboard*. Then push *that* instance.

Or even better, do this: make a *segue* (a push segue) from S1 to S2 in the storyboard, and give *it* an identifier. Then to go there, you don't need to instantiate *anything*; you just run the segue by calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

Comment: And see the explanation, in my book, of how storyboards work: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_storyboards - You really should stop and read that whole chapter, actually, before going any further (though to be honest you've done quite well so far!).

Comment: Thank you so much for all the detail. I'll go check the link.